# GlassFish - "asadmin create-service --name domain1" error

Tags: glassfish-4

1. I downloaded glassFish 4.1.1.
2. Extract it.
3. Open cmd, and go to extracted glassfish's bin directory.
4. Wrote this line "asadmin create-service --name domain1".
5. I already did this before and I don't remember any error. I just format this PC and want to create a service of my glassFish but it gives error.

error:
[image]

What should I do to fix this? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the `cmd` shell as Administrator...